# Numba nested function won't execute (version 0.47)

Tags: python, numba

I'm confused as to why this doesn't work, the docs say:

*2.6.1.2.3. Inner function and closure:
 Numba now supports inner functions as long as they are non-recursive and only called locally, but not passed as argument or returned as result. The use of closure variables (variables defined in outer scopes) within an 
inner function is also supported.*

```
import numba

@numba.jit(nopython=True, debug=False, parallel=False, cache=True)
def outer() -> int:

    @numba.jit(nopython=True, debug=False, parallel=False, cache=True)
    def inner() -> int:
        return 1

    return inner()

outer()
```

And the error:

```
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: analyzing bytecode)
op_MAKE_FUNCTION with annotations is not implemented
```

Am I doing something silly here?

(os: Ubuntu 19.10)

Comment: Are you doing a deliberate test of whether `numba` supports type hinting? If not, removing `-> int` will probably solve your problem. If so, it's probably a bug and unless someone who actually knows numba says it's not, I'd recommend you [report it by filing an issue in the github repository](https://github.com/numba/numba) or some similar action.

Comment: I tried that (removing type hinting), it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soln: Don't use type declarations and remove the inner jit decorator